# How to enforce CSS overflow?

Tags: html, css

Picture this:

I have a parent element that has a `max-width` of `800px` but otherwise no `min-width`, filling the available space using

```
flex: 1;
```

Now, I’d like for this element to have a child table, which I would like to overflow when the parent element shrinks. That is, I’d want the `max-width` of that table to be the current `width` of the parent element.

The situation could probably be summarized as such:

```html
<main style="max-width: 800px; flex: 1;">
 <article style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
   <!-- some more elements wrapping the table, also being set to 100% width & max-width -->
   <table style="overflow-x: scroll; width: 100%; max-width: 100%;"></table>
 </article>
</main>
```

This doesn't work. Instead of stopping at the current width of the `main` component, the table expands to 800px and only then overflows.

How could I solve this?

Here's some minimal working code demonstrating the problem:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  background: white;
}

article {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table,
tbody {
  max-width: 100%;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>
    What I need is for the main component to be able to shrink below its max width when the window shrinks, and for its children to overflow when it does. What happens now is that overflowing children force the main element to be at max height.
  </h1>
  <main>
    <article>
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                This text is here demonstrates that it's not overflowing as it should but instead filling the parent to its max width (800px)
              </td>
              <td>
                This text is here demonstrates that it's not overflowing as it should but instead filling the parent to its max width (800px)
              </td>
              <td>
                This text is here demonstrates that it's not overflowing as it should but instead filling the parent to its max width (800px)
              </td>
              <td>
                This text is here demonstrates that it's not overflowing as it should but instead filling the parent to its max width (800px)
              </td>
              <td>
                This text is here demonstrates that it's not overflowing as it should but instead filling the parent to its max width (800px)
              </td>
              <td>
                This text is here demonstrates that it's not overflowing as it should but instead filling the parent to its max width (800px)
              </td>
              <td>
                This text is here demonstrates that it's not overflowing as it should but instead filling the parent to its max width (800px)
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </article>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *Instead of stopping at the current width of the main component* --> what is that *current width* ?

Comment: Sorry, that is some bad wording. What I had in mind is that the table component locks itself to 800px, preventing the main component from shrinking, effectively rendering its width fixed to 800px.

Comment: min-width:0 on main ?

Comment: Did not work, I tried that already.

Comment: share a full working code then

Comment: The code is not mine, I'm trying to modify the table from `rich-markdown-editor` React library to overflow nicely with global css rules. I've been tinkering around in the web inspector & global css rules but nothing seems to work. It has no other css properties that would affect width or overflow than I described.

Comment: try to recreate a minimal code that reproduce the behavior otherwise we cannot help

Comment: Here, I edited the post to include it

Comment: your code behave as you want, the main shrink if you decrease the browser width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around some more with the CSS properties, the solution to my problem was adding `display: flex` and `min-width: 0px` to the `<main>` element's parent.